# Load More Item js is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to have a list of product item in one div that will be load after click on "Load more". It is working well without "use strict";. But When I use "use strict"; it doesn't seem to work.  Here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/mdmonir/ou4sjtan/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>    
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lack of `var` before variable declarations. Add that and you should be golden. In this case the `"use strict"` directive is preventing you from unintentionally polluting the global scope with variables. As a result, we need to be explicitly clear about their intended scope:

```js
var size_li = $("#myList li").size();
var x = 3;
```

Upon adding `var` before each declaration, the demo will proceed to work.